# Reverse engineer pl/sql to flowchart or any other diagram

Tags: plsql

Does anyone know of an open source/free tool for converting pl/sql code to a flowchart or data flow or activity diagram?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I don't.  Data flow and activity diagrams are at a much higher level of abstraction than PL/SQL code, so it wouldn't make sense to try to generate those from PL/SQL.  Flowcharts are for code, but I thought they went out of vogue about 25 years ago?  They are so pointless.

What you can get are IDEs like SQL Developer (free), Toad etc. that can show the structure of your code, allow you to collapse logical blocks of code, colour code the different elements of the code, indent code etc.

Comment: Hi, I am using sqldeveloper and eclipse and they do help with the collapsable logical blocks. For code that is comprised of thousands of lines it is not really easy to follow even with the logical blocks. I have seen several tools for converting pl/sql to dataflow diagrams but they are all commercial.

Answer (score 4):

- Visustin v6 Flow chart generator
- Code Visual to Flowchart 3.5

They are not really freeware but you can do pretty much everything using their free version.

Answer (score 0):

It might be of help to build a kind of three with a query through `dba_dependencies:`

```
select lpad(name, length(name)+3*level, ' ')
,      type
,      prior name
--,      prior type
from   dba_dependencies
start 
with   name='&enter_your_package'
and    type='PACKAGE'
connect 
by     nocycle 
       name = prior referenced_name
and    type = prior referenced_type
;
```